# Run python file in child package from console

Tags: python, module, console

This is my project structure:

```
/project
|    /package
|    |    __init__.py
|    |    module1.py
|    |    module2.py
|    main.py
```

In `main.py`, I import `module1.py`. In `module1.py`, I import `module2.py`:

#### module1.py

```
from package import module2
#do something
```

I run `python main.py` OK. But when I run `python module1.py` (inside `package`) or `python /package/module1.py` (inside `project`), I got `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package/module1.py", line 5, in <module>
    from package import engine
ImportError: No module named 'package'
```

When I run `module1.py` in PyCharm, it's OK.

So, my question is : **how to run file `module1.py` without `main.py`**?

Thank you.

Comment: Add your project directory to [PYTHONPATH][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sol 1:** When you use `from package import module2` python does not know where to look for **package** unless its added to path. You can running it as

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project python module1.py
```

**Sol 2:**  If *module1.py* and *module2.py* are in the same folder, you don't need to use `from package import module2`.
 Just using `import module2` should be fine. Now running module1.py will work.

**Sol 3:** If you insist on using `from package import module2`. You cant append path to package in your script

```
import sys                                               
from os.path import dirname, abspath                     
sys.path.insert(0, dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))))  
from package import module2
```